# hide a row in activeadmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin

I'm using activeadmin with Ruby 2.2.1 and Rails 4.2.0 for a trouble ticketing system. I need to hide/archive the closed tickets, but I don't know how...

```
index do
 selectable_column
 column :ticket
 column :in_carico
 column :inoltrato
 column :categoria
 column :oggetto do |n|
   truncate(n.oggetto, omision: "...", length: 50)
 end
 column :note do |n|
   truncate(n.note, omision: "...", length: 30)
 end
 column :created_at
 column :stato
 actions defaults: true do |a|
   link_to 'Infoweb', "http://XXX/main/ticket_dettagli.asp?TT="+a.ticket , :target => "_blank"
end
```

end

In :stato I can choose 3 voices: working, suspended and closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example using `Post` model.

You can  register a model in AA for archived posts (`/admin/archived_posts.rb`):

```
ActiveAdmin.register Post, as: "Archived Posts" do
end
```

Then in Post model define a scope, returning only post, where, for example, `status` attribute is `archived`:

```
scope :archived, -> { where(status: 'archived') }
```

Then in already registered model in AA you use this scope in `scoped_collection` method:

```
  ActiveAdmin.register Post, as: "Archived Posts" do
    # ...
    controller do
      def scoped_collection
        Post.archived
      end
    end
    # ...
  end
```

This is it, you have all the archived posts in this new tab of AA.

Of course, now, to not have posts, where `status` is `archived` in regular Post tab in AA (`/admin/posts.rb`), add new scope to `Post` model (`/models/post.rb`):

```
scope :not_archived, -> { where.not(status: 'archived') } # or something like this
```

and use it in `scoped_collection` method in `/admin/posts.rb`